# Find string between 2 points & move between another 2 points

Tags: java, php, html, mysql, centos

I have a lot of urls that are sadly static, to change them I need to use some type of application or script.. I have about 400 files with urls ranging from 15-150 on each.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Change:
<td class="SELECTX"><strong>Text example 1 <a href=""></a>Text Example 2 </strong></td>

To:
<td class="SELECTX"><strong> <a href=""></a>Text example 1 Text Example 2 </strong></td>
```

I would love a way to change this on all files at once, but if I can't then at least a way to where I can change all urls on 1 file without having to do manual cut and paste.

I searched and searched for over 3 hours and found nothing... I hope someone can help.

Edit:
Basically I'm trying to find the text/string between `<strong` and `<a href=` which would be `"Text example 1"` then move it to go after `""></a>` . Which would now come before `"Text Example 2"`

Comment: Your example doesn't seem to be doing much other than moving the `<a>` tags around. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish? Also, is this Java, php, or MySQL? What environment do you want to use for solving this?

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific, I'm trying to find the text/string between <strong and <a href= which would be "Text example 1" then move it to go after ""></a> . Which would now come before "Text Example 2"

Comment: Yes, but I don't really need to do this server side, even a site like http://jsfiddle.net might be helpful as all I will do is then take the results and overwrite the old static urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash 
while read line
do
     x=`echo $line |grep -o "strong>.*<a" | sed 's/strong>//' |sed 's/<a//'`
     y=`echo $line |grep -o "a>.*</strong" | sed 's/a>//' |sed 's/<\/strong//'`
     z=`echo $line| sed 's/'"$x"'//' |sed 's/'"$y"'/'"$x $y"'/'`
    echo $z
done < a.txt
```

Append the output of this script to another file and that will be your expected output. You can put a for loop to iterate all the files in that directory.

If you want to replicate this in java here is the logic.

String X = "Text example 1"

String Y = "Text example 2"

String Z = X+(concatenate)+ Y

replace "Text example 1" with ' '

replace"Text example 2" with String Z.

Comment: Seems like this would work, but not to ask a dumb question. How would I go about executing this? Would there be a way to post the results on the same page?

BTW I'm using a Linux server if that makes a difference.

Comment: Its a shell script. Copy all those lines and put it in a file called b.sh. Dont forget to change a.txt to your input file.
Go to terminal
chmod +x b.sh
./b.sh >> outputfile.txt
Now the output file.txt contains the replaced string or you can put sed -i inside the script to change the input file itself..

Comment: The only problem with this answer is that it is not one of the languages tagged in this question.  You also make the assumption that Bassam has a linux machine (or a machine that can execute these commands), even though he never indicated he is running linux or windows. I would not provide an answer in Fortran for a PDP11 because it works even if the OP did ask "is this possible".

Comment: my example contains the logic. he can replicate the same in java. I have only done pattern replacing.

Comment: I have added the logic there. Now you can replicate this in java

Comment: I do have a linux box with CentOS, is there no way the java script can be excused without going through shh? Like excusing it by going to its path on a browser.

Answer (score 0):

To find the string between the two  (or ) tag's I'd probably just use a regular expression to find where in the file the strings are, then process each string/line in a script.

Then maybe for each line, find the opening  tag and the closing  tag which would give me the indexes of the section of the string that needs swapping, and swap the 2 pieces along the index of the opening  tag.

Comment: The example I gave has all the strings/text that exist, I just didn't include the example text because its always different and wouldn't be useful for a mass find between & move.

Comment: Oh, my answer was missing a few words while posting. But yes, I figured both the URL inside the A tag and the example text would vary (and be any length), which was why I would search along the 'Strong' and 'A' opening and closing tags (as those should be the same?).

Answer (score 0):

Please check this it works exactly for your need

```
    String s = "<td class=\"SELECTX\"><strong>Text example 1 <a href=\"\"></a>Text Example 2 </strong></td>";
    s = s.replace("<a href=\"\"></a>", " ").replace("<strong>", "<strong><a href=\"\"></a>");
```